# What something for / What for / For what

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, difference, questions

What is the difference? Which one is correct?

> ***what*** do you need it ***for***?
>
> ***what for*** do you need it?
>
> ***for what*** do you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what do you need it for? - correct, informal and conversational, widely used.

what for do you need it? - broken English. Do not use. Will be heard as "wrong" by native speakers.

for what do you need it? - correct - more formal.

Comment: In practice, we're probably more likely to ask ***Why** do you need it?* rather than ***What** do you need it **for**?* Just sayin'.

Comment: Yes, "what for" can be equivalent to "why", but a question about the intended use or purpose of something can very often be formed like "What do you need caustic soda for?", where the answer could be like "I need it for unblocking a drain-pipe". I don't know about "more likely".